# Python XML Parsing without root

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-2.7, elementtree

I wanted to parse a fairly huge xml-like file which doesn't have any root element. The format of the file is:

```
<tag1>
<tag2>
</tag2>
</tag1>

<tag1>
<tag3/>
</tag1>
```

What I tried:

1. tried using ElementTree but it returned a "no root" error. (Is there any other python library which can be used for parsing this file?)
2. tried adding an extra tag to wrap the entire file and then parse it using Element-Tree. However, I would like to use some more efficient method, in which I would not need to alter the original xml file.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: It contains over 3 million useful terms (apart from the tags and other unnecessary data)

Comment: Approximate file size?  Are you looking for time efficiency or memory efficiency?  Can the whole file be read into memory?

Answer (score 10):

`lxml.html` can parse *fragments*:

```
from lxml import html
s = """<tag1>
 <tag2>
 </tag2>
</tag1>

<tag1>
 <tag3/>
</tag1>"""
doc = html.fromstring(s)
for thing in doc:
    print thing
    for other in thing:
        print other
"""
>>> 
<Element tag1 at 0x3411a80>
<Element tag2 at 0x3428990>
<Element tag1 at 0x3428930>
<Element tag3 at 0x3411a80>
>>>
"""
```

Courtesy [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165913/2823755)

And if there is more than one level of nesting:

```
def flatten(nested):
    """recusively flatten nested elements

    yields individual elements
    """
    for thing in nested:
        yield thing
        for other in flatten(thing):
            yield other
doc = html.fromstring(s)
for thing in flatten(doc):
    print thing
```

Similarly, `lxml.etree.HTML` will parse this.  It adds html and body tags:

```
d = etree.HTML(s)
for thing in d.iter():
    print thing

""" 
<Element html at 0x3233198>
<Element body at 0x322fcb0>
<Element tag1 at 0x3233260>
<Element tag2 at 0x32332b0>
<Element tag1 at 0x322fcb0>
<Element tag3 at 0x3233148>
"""
```

Answer (score 9):

[`ElementTree.fromstringlist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstringlist) accepts an iterable (that yields strings).

Using it with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

with open('xml-like-file.xml') as f:
    it = itertools.chain('<root>', f, '</root>')
    root = ET.fromstringlist(it)

# Do something with `root`
root.find('.//tag3')
```

Comment: I guess this would not be an efficient method in case of large files. Also as I said earlier, I would like to implement this using a different method rather than adding tags to the input.

Comment: @sgp, I should write `f` instead of `f.read()`. updated.; At least this does not read the whole content at once.

Comment: Don't you think that perhaps using a different library would be better? I mean again, you are just adding extra tags to the xml, right? Could you explain me why do you think your method is efficient? Thanks :)

Comment: @sgp, Because this does not load the whole contents at once as I said in the previous comment. I didn't benchmark the solutions; I can't tell that which one perform better. (BTW, try `cElementTree` instead of `ElementTree`)

Answer (score 8):

How about instead of editing the file do something like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with file("xml-file.xml") as f:
    xml_object = ET.fromstringlist(["<root>", f.read(), "</root>"])
```

Comment: In my question, I have said that I already tried this and I would like a better method than that. As the file is large enough, the method you suggested is not an efficient one.

Comment: @sgp You said you edited the original file. That's not what this does. *I would like to use some more efficient method, in which I would not need to alter the original xml file* ... The original file is unchanged.

Comment: In practice, both are the same methods aren't they? You basically added the extra tag to the string. I would rather like to have a library that doesn't give a "no root error". This method is not a good one because as the file size is large, the process of adding a tag to the string would take some time, thereby causing the inefficiency.

Comment: @sgp See my updated answer I know longer edit the string. This is more efficient than editing the feel. I only write to memory and not to disk.

Comment: @sgp - adding the two tags in this and falsetru's solution is trivial. It adds them *on-the-fly* - there is no extra iteration over the file contents, it is not constructing a complete new string with the added tags.