# Python XML Parsing without root v2

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, parsing, xml-parsing

I have 100,000 XML files that look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<reiXml>
  <program>BB</program>
  <nazivStavbe>Test build</nazivStavbe>
  <X>101000</X>
  <Y>462000</Y>
  <QNH>24788</QNH>
  <QNC>9698</QNC>
  <Qf>255340</Qf>
  <Qp>597451</Qp>
  <CO2>126660</CO2>
  <An>1010.7</An>
  <Vc>3980</Vc>
  <A>2362.8</A>
  <Ht>0.336</Ht>
  <f0>0.59</f0>
...
</reiXml>
```

I want to extract around 10 numbers from each, e.g. An, Vc... but i have a problem since the XML files doesn't have a root name.
I looked up to other cases on this forum, but I can't seem to replicate their solutions (e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891295/python-xml-parsing-without-root)).

So I have basically 2 problems: 1) how to read multiple XML files and 2) extract certain values from it... and put that in 1 txt file with 100,000 rows :(

The final result would be something like:

```
          An     Vc
XMLfile1 1010.7  3980
XMLfile2 ...     ...
XMLfile3 ...     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `beautifulsoup` to parse the XML files?

```py
xml_doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<reiXml>
  <program>BB</program>
  <nazivStavbe>Test build</nazivStavbe>
  <X>101000</X>
  <Y>462000</Y>
  <QNH>24788</QNH>
  <QNC>9698</QNC>
  <Qf>255340</Qf>
  <Qp>597451</Qp>
  <CO2>126660</CO2>
  <An>1010.7</An>
  <Vc>3980</Vc>
  <A>2362.8</A>
  <Ht>0.336</Ht>
  <f0>0.59</f0>
</reiXml>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

print(soup.An.text)
print(soup.Vc.text)
```

Prints:

```
1010.7
3980
```

---

EDIT: To create a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

files = ["file1.xml", ...other files]

all_data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f_in:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "xml")
        all_data.append({"file": file, "An": soup.An.text, "Vc": soup.Vc.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).set_index("file")
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           An    Vc
file1.xml  1010.7  3980
```

Comment: This works! I wasn't familiar with `beautifulsoup`. How would I make a dataframe with `An` and `Vc` as columns and XML files as rows?

Comment: @energyMax Can you please edit your question and put example output dataframe there?

Comment: Of course. I've put a sample ouput in the description

Comment: Great. Regarding the `files` commend. SInce i have 100,000 files, should i create a simple command on how to write the names, do you think this would be the best option?

Comment: Is there any command, that would real all files in a folder?

Comment: @energyMax I suggest to look at [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module or `os.walk` etc. to iterate over all files. For example `glob.glob('./*.xml')` should give you all *.xml filenames in current directory.

Comment: Do you perhaps know why I get an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` from the `all_data.append` command?

Comment: Shoud the problem with "NoneType" be addressed in the `append` function?

Comment: @DevOps Shoud the problem with "NoneType" be addressed in the append function?

Comment: @energyMax That means some XML files doesn't have `<An>` and/or  `<Vc>`. You should check this before accessing `.text` property and handle it.

Comment: But it does. So I assume the code is not reading my XML at all... and i must fix this

Comment: @DevOps I don't understant. The XML is in the same folder as the script and the problem remains...

Comment: @DevOps Andrej, can we get on a quick chat please?

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering my own question, but I'll edit the solution later.

If I use the solution from previous post, I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The values are in the XML file, so i really don't know what to do...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since bs4 doesn't work well with XML files, would it be possible to recreate this code with lxml?