# Script doesn't recognize values in XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

This is not answering my own question, but I'll edit the solution later. This is a follow-up question from topic [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136140/python-xml-parsing-without-root-v2/74136951#74136951).

If I use the solution from this post, I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The values are in the XML file, so i really don't know what to do...

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

files = ["S1.xml"]


#files = glob.glob('./*.xml')

all_data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f_in:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "xml")
        all_data.append({"file": file, "A": soup.A.text, "Qfl": soup.Qfl.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).set_index("file")
df.index.name = None
print(df)
```

A sample od S1.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<reiXmlPrenos>
  <QNH>24788</QNH>
  <QNC>9698</QNC>
  <RefKlima>42774.8</RefKlima>
  <Qf>255340</Qf>
  <Qp>597451</Qp>
  <CO2>126660</CO2>
  <A>2362.8</A>
  <Ht>0.336</Ht>
  <f0>0.59</f0>
  <z>0.105891</z>
  <TP>3300</TP>
  <Qfaux>2126</Qfaux>
  <Qfh>24065</Qfh>
  <Qfc>5345</Qfc>
  <Qfv>18177</Qfv>
  <Qfst>0</Qfst>
  <Qfw>195520</Qfw>
  <Qfl>10107</Qfl>
  <fOVE>6.4</fOVE>
</reiXmlPrenos>
```

The error I get

```
  File "<ipython-input-163-14360bc9577e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/......py', wdir='....n')

  File ".....py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File ".....py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File ".....py", line 25, in <module>
    all_data.append({"file": file, "A": soup.A.text})

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as image

Comment: Same for `s1.xml`.

Comment: @Daweo Edited in the description.

Comment: @JackFleeting    Edited in the description.

Comment: What is the information you try to extract from the xml?

Comment: I want to extract e.g. 10 values from XML (in this case `A` and  `Qfl` only and put values as colums. Then I'd like to repeat that with several 1,000 XML files... where each XML would represent one row.  In this case i'm trying first to do that with 1 XML... but if you have solution for 1.) solving the "NoneType" issue and 2) reading from several thousands of XML files in the same folder at the same time... this would be perfect!

Comment: Works for me with the xml sample and provided code. OP should inspect the failing XML file and check syntax, namespaces, etc. Also, it would help to post the exact stack trace of the error .

Comment: @LMC I copied the trace of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does not reproduce with provided sample so it could be a problem with a particular file. Adding a try-except would help to catch the problematic filename

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

files = ["S1.xml"]


#files = glob.glob('./*.xml')

all_data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f_in:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "xml")
            all_data.append({"file": file, "A": soup.A.text, "Qfl": soup.Qfl.text})
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(f'Error: {file}, {e}')

if all_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).set_index("file")
    df.index.name = None
    print(df)
```

A simple way to reproduce the error is to comment out `A` element on provided sample

```
  <!--<A>2362.8</A>-->
```

Comment: It does indeed work if I copy the xml content into a new file... but it doesn't work on the old xml file. It always returns an error ˛Error: S1.xml, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'˛

Comment: Which is confusing, since it may be the case that thousands of xml files have the same error/are corrupt...

Comment: Copy how? Copy&Paste? look carefully at the source file. Can you open it in a browser? Does it look correct?

Comment: Yes - simple copy-paste works.  i don't have an explanation for this. I can open it in a browser, it looks fine... is there any way i can send it to you, just to see if you get an error as well?

Comment: If there are no privacy issues you can use pastebin. YOu can also try parsing it with `lxml` module and see if it works.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bXkDQJRb     - i copied the entire content from the xml that is "troubling"

Comment: Worked also but I was able to reproduce with `BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "lxml")` or `BeautifulSoup(f_in.read())` so it could be caused by parsers available on your system. Got a warning `XMLParsedAsHTMLWarning: It looks like you're parsing an XML document using an HTML parser` and then the attribute error

Comment: Hmm. Is there a solution maybe if this keeps happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248950/discussion-between-lmc-and-energymax).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<reiXmlPrenos>
  <QNH>24788</QNH>
  <QNC>9698</QNC>
  <RefKlima>42774.8</RefKlima>
  <Qf>255340</Qf>
  <Qp>597451</Qp>
  <CO2>126660</CO2>
  <A>2362.8</A>
  <Ht>0.336</Ht>
  <f0>0.59</f0>
  <z>0.105891</z>
  <TP>3300</TP>
  <Qfaux>2126</Qfaux>
  <Qfh>24065</Qfh>
  <Qfc>5345</Qfc>
  <Qfv>18177</Qfv>
  <Qfst>0</Qfst>
  <Qfw>195520</Qfw>
  <Qfl>10107</Qfl>
  <fOVE>6.4</fOVE>
</reiXmlPrenos>'''
elements = ['A', 'Qfl']
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for el_str in elements:
    el = root.find(el_str)
    if el is not None:
        print(f'{el_str} --> {el.txt}')
    else:
        print(f'{el_str} --> None')
```

output

```
2362.8
10107
```

Comment: This works. But if you look at a comment above, i'm trying to use the code on several 1,000 files... so this solution is not the most suitable for me

Comment: Why not ? Just take this code and nest it under a `for` loop.

Comment: I don't know how. And I don't know how to define the folder with all the XML files